# Why spring bean can support not only String[] but also String

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-bean

This is Spring bean source.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Bean {
    @AliasFor("name")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor("value")
    String[] name() default {};

    Autowire autowire() default Autowire.NO;

    String initMethod() default "";

    String destroyMethod() default AbstractBeanDefinition.INFER_METHOD;
```

I had noticed that `String[] value() default {};`. It means that we have to use String Array. But I use the code below, passed a String there, It still works, please tell me why.

```
@Bean("user")
public UserBean get() {
    return new UserBean();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In an array you can put 0 or several values, it's up to you. That simply means that you can give 0 or several aliases to your bean.

```
@Bean(value={"user","otherUser","..."})
public UserBean get() {
  return new UserBean();
}
```

**EDIT**
*Why `"user"` is accepted even if it's not an array?*

So, in Java you can declare a String object like this :

```
String value = "value1"; //this is a String
String user = "user"; // this is another String
String str = ""; //this is an empty string
```

Note that they are defined with `""`, so `"user"` is a String.

Now in this case whe have an array of String, that means we have an object which is a container of String.

```
String[] values=new String[]{};//this is an array of String, an object where we can put many Strings.
```

As `"user"` is a String, you can put it int the array `values`, something like this :

```
values[0]="user";
```

When you declare you bean like this :

```
@Bean("user")
public UserBean get() {
  return new UserBean();
}
```

In reality, you put the String `"user"` in the array of strings returned by the method :

```
String[] value() default {};
```

That why `"user"` is accepted because it's simply a String

Comment: But in `@Bean("user")`, `"user"` is not a array. Can java support it?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is an array in Java. Check here : https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-string-array-reference-java-5-for-loop-syntax

Comment: Did you see why `"user"` is accepted in this case or not?

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand it. Could you help me?

Comment: Please check the edit, I tryed to explain why `"user"` is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same concepts of the main method in Java.

`public static void main(String[] args)`

You can call your main method passing no parameters, one, two or how many you want.